# RPi data collection interrupted by WiFi

Tags: wifi, php

I have a Raspberry Pi running a solar array. Thr array feeds charge controller which feeds the RPi.
The RPi drives the array positioning circuitry (single-axis traqcking) and performs data collection duties.
The data collection script is PHP, the graphing script is Javascript, the array positioinng script is Python.

There is a problem with the RPi's ability to run uninterrupted.
The charge controller is not connected to the router by cable, but by WiFi.
A problem occurs when the router/modem is powered up. Most of a line of data is lost.
The data collection script collects fifteen data points. Fifteen for each line of the table, a CSV file.
The collection is done every thirty seconds.
When the router/modem is powered up, the first eleven or twelve are lost. This occurs for only one line during each power up, but is still troublesome.
I intend to leave the RPi running continuously. I also have a script that publishes the data on a webpage. When the data gap occurs, the graphing script stops plotting. the page is blank.
I've noticed, in the past, too many scripts running will cause similar interruptions in operation.
The data collection script is in PHP.

Is there a way to disable the WiFi during a data collection operation?

Comment: you say the problem occurs when `the router/modem is powered up` - what does this have to do with being able to `disable the WiFi` (presumably on the pi since you've asked in a Raspberry Pi forum) - disabling the Wifi on a pi isn't going to change the state of the "router/modem" which is the source of the problem (according to you)

Answer (score 0):

"I've noticed, in the past, too many scripts running will cause similar interruptions in operation. The data collection script is in PHP."

I surmise the RPi can't keep up the activity while processing the WiFi connection. No doubt the WiFi connect engages the RPi. This activity causes the data stream from the charge controller (RJ-45) to skip some data transfers. Some sort of overload condition occurs, time-wise. I just examined this evenings dataset and found no skips during the router/DSL modem power up. My conclusion is a traffic jam occasionally occurs. My solution: minimize unrelated activity.

The single, litigatory, response was neither helpful, nor useful.

Comment: I don't get it, if the router is powering up, it can't send those datalines, so it's normal you loose data. It sounds like it's a scripting problem that doesn't not look if a connection is available and just yells the data without knowing if someone is listening.